# Bitnami PostgresSQL Helm chart wipes data on restart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami

I have a cluster on AWS EKS with a PostgreSQL pod installed using the following Helm command:

`helm install postgresql-default -f helm-values/values_postgresql.yaml bitnami/postgresql`

I have a persistent volume:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgresql-pv
spec:
  storageClassName: efs-sc
capacity:
  storage: 10Gi
volumeMode: Filesystem
persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
accessModes:
 - ReadWriteOnce
csi:
  driver: efs.csi.aws.com
  volumeHandle: fs-xxxxxxxx
```

and claim in the cluster:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgresql-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
requests:
  storage: 1Gi
```

Contents of values_postgresql.yaml: https://pastebin.com/cY5v9vfB

Everything works fine until I kill the pod `kubectl delete pod postgresql-default-0`. All data is being wiped out. When I check the pod, I can see that it has two containers:
[image]
I wonder if it is the init container that is causing the data loss and how I can run the PostgreSQL pod without running init script every time it restarts.

Comment: can you post the content of `helm-values/values_postgresql.yaml `

Comment: seems like the chart create own pv and does not respect your one

Comment: @Adiii, how did you come to that conclusion? When I check the contents of `helm-values/values_postgresql.yaml`, I can see this: `persistence:    existingClaim: postgresql-pv-claim` so I guess it should use the existing PVC in the cluster.